# text box aspx cow ai can add data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, textbox

as if I can read or write in the rows below selected ?
work environment asp.net , vb language .
any solution is welcome ,
I have to create a text box with the data below , thanks

P.S. the image is in the link below

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/439x67q90/911/vd4WqM.png

Comment: This is not a code-writing service, show us what you have written so far and we may be able to help with any problems you're having

Comment: i have only 
   <asp:Label ID="PARTITA_IVA" runat="server" Text="Label">inserisci Partita la IVA </asp:Label>